# How to bind a colormap to an array?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, colors

I would like to get an array of colors starting from an array values.

for example:

```
a = [4,3,2,5,6,20,1,34]
```

I expect to had a new array with color like a viridis cmap of matplotlib, where the small numbers are binded (same index) with dark colors and the big numbers with  light color.

Comment: how do those numbers relate to colors?

Comment: There are not particulary relationships , i'm only interested to have light colors for the higher numbers into the array. Just like a heat map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`matplotlib.pyplot.Normalize`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Normalize.html) so the data is normalized to the `[0-1]` interval when fed to the plot function.
Here is an example of what it would look like, using the normalized ranges

```
a = [4,3,2,5,6,20,1,34]
# An example colormap
colormap = plt.cm.cool 
# Normalize using the min and max values in a
normalize = plt.Normalize(vmin=min(a), vmax=max(a))
# scatter plot with the parameters defined above
plt.scatter(range(len(a)), y=a, c=a, cmap=colormap, marker='o')
```

[image]

Note that you will have to use `a` as the `c` argument in [`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html), which as mentioned in the docs accepts:

> Color, sequence, or sequence of color, optional

So this way you will be using the array `a` to select values from the colormap which will in turn be normalized by the `,ax` and `min` values in `a`.

Comment: Thank you ! I needed exactly what plt.scatter returns.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply make an array with rgb colours in it like this:

```
colors = ["rgb(0, 0, 0)"]
```

And each possible number could have an entry in the array. So the number zero in this example would return the rgb for black.